# Changing read-only files created by installation

Tags: c#, file, io, installshield

I have an XNA game and I created an InstallShield installer for it. The game saves data into several txt file in the install location. That was working without any problem using the debugger or just running from the bin folder. But once installed, the txt that I need to write the preferences becomes read-only and so the game crashes each time it tries to write a file. How can I solve that?

Comment: I cant see that there is enough information in this question to give any kind of answer.  Please add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's by design, and I agree with the design. There may be more than one user on a system, and you're doing a system-wide install of your software, so every user gets it. Those users shouldn't and probably don't want to share game saves.

Either you should install your game to a per-user location, or you should move the save data away from where your executable is located. Whichever of those you choose, you will have solved the problem you're having now.

Comment: Does this only happens when the files are located in the same folder as the executable or can I just put them in a folder next to the exe?

Comment: @user26830 It happens when the program attempts to save somewhere the user has no write permissions for, and it is independent of where the executable is located. If the executable is located in %PROGRAMFILES%\YourGame, and the save data is located in %PROGRAMFILES%\YourGame, the user normally won't be able to write to it. If the executable is located in %PROGRAMFILES%\YourGame, and the save data is located in %PROGRAMFILES%\YourGameData, the user still normally won't be able to write to it. Why aren't you storing your game data in %APPDATA%\YourGame?

Comment: That's what I just did and works perfectly I was just curious about how the system was working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user26830 Ah, okay. For that, I may be able to elaborate a bit: InstallShield doesn't specifically handle folder permissions. If you open the properties of C:\Program Files in Windows Explorer, and look at the Security tab, you'll see that write permissions are not granted for ordinary users. When InstallShield creates a subdirectory inside C:\Program Files, it inherits the parent's permissions. It works the same way when you create your own directory in %APPDATA%: it is already writable by the user, so you don't need to do anything special to write to a newly created subdirectory there.

Comment: The ProgramFiles folder has always (even on XP) been restricted in that limited users can't update/create files there. Everyone was admin back then and didn't notice. Since UAC everyone is limited unless explicitly elevated (such as with a requiresAdministrator manifest in the program if it really needs admin privs).